# How to use a file(say excel sheet) of one job to another job in jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

I have a excel sheet in Job 1 of Jenkins.Now I want to use/copy it in my Job 2.How could do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

On the job 2, you will be able to get the Excel sheet from the job 1, if the sheet is archived as an artifact.

The other solution is to user the [Shared Workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin).

On the job 1, you can archive the workspace and reuse it for the job 2.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I am not very sure whether I will be able to add these plugins, as i am using Organizational Jenkins.So Is there any other way

Comment: If you are not able to use plugins, the other solution is to work on network shared drives (something accessible from your 2 jobs).